# How to format seaborn/matplotlib distplots

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to make the following image look a lot nicer:

[image: my example]

Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)
sns.distplot(list1, ax=ax[0])
sns.distplot(list2,ax=ax[1])
sns.distplot(list3,ax=ax[2])
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

I'd like to make it so the distributions look much bigger (for presentations). They look so cramped and hard to read for other professionals.
and also add titles to each of the 3 distributions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use figsize to manually set the subplot size

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(6,5))

sns.distplot(a, ax=ax[0][0])
ax[0][0].set_title('a')

sns.distplot(b,ax=ax[0][1])
ax[0][1].set_title('b')

sns.distplot(c,ax=ax[1][0])
ax[1][0].set_title('c')

fig.suptitle('distplots')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

You should get something like this
[image]

If you dont want the fourth empty subplot just add fizsize() and suitable values in your code